# how to solve Curl error in cpanel with its version

Tags: curl

I m facing issues with `curl` today many of my clients complained to update `curl` so I decided to update it to 7.70 latest

so I did that but after installation and everything. I m facing something strange

when I run these commands `curl-config --version` and `curl --version`, they return the correct version 7.70.0

but when I run this `/usr/bin/curl -V` I get 7.29 and even the users are still getting the old version. Can you please help me with this?.

in cpanel

Comment: What output do you get when you type `which curl`?

Comment: 7.29 but with curl --version I get 7.70

Comment: ‘which curl’ should give you a path, not a version. What path does it show you?